# IOS Subview Autoresizing rounds frame values

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a UIImageView which contains a collection of subviews which have been dynamically added onto it. Each subview has very precise frame values. i.e. x=114.252 y=123.642 width=169.323 height=35.3234. I need these values to be that precise. The problem is if I set the UIImageView to autoresize subviews and set the resize mask on each of the subviews then change the frame of the UIImageView, each subview's frame then contains a rounded result. i.e. height becomes 35.

Is there anyway to stop these values being rounded?

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using autoresizing, you can subclass UIImageView and implement `layoutSubviews` to perform layout manually on your subviews. This method will be called automatically when the UIImageView's frame is changed.

Keep in mind, however, that autoresizing behaves that way for a reason. A view whose frame is not integral will probably not be displayed correctly (because the display, through physical limitations of the hardware, is quantized by the pixel, and there is only one pixel to a point - or, on a double resolution screen, two pixels to a point). So the autoresizing mechanism was probably calling `NSRectIntegral()` for you - and ultimately you may want to call it yourself.

Comment: Makes sense and managed to get a working solution. Thanks Jon!